# usbmon, the usb spec and endianness/byte-order

Tags: usb, endianness

I am trying to decipher a trace of USB I/O traffic produced by `usbmon` and am having some issues getting my head around the endianness.  For the sake of example, here are two lines from the trace I am working with:

```
ffff8800650e7000 433121059 S Ci:2:000:0 s 80 06 0100 0000 0040 64 <
ffff8800650e7000 433121661 C Ci:2:000:0 0 18 = 12010002 00000040 da0b8781 00010102 0301
```

I initially had no suspicion whatsoever of anything other than big-endianness in the trace, but then I saw `da0b8781` in the second line, which corresponds to the identity of the USB device I am tracing which has a vendor ID of `0x0bda` and product ID of `0x8187` (note the reversal of byte-order in the trace).

So at this point I thought that maybe within a given field of a `usbmon` trace, the bytes were always in reverse byte order and should be interpreted as such.  But to the contrary, let's examine a small part near the end of the first trace line, `... 0040 64`

`0040` is a hex field representing the maximum accepted response size.  `64` is a decimal field that should represent exactly the same thing.  `0x0040` = `64` decimal, *without switching the byte order* to `0x4000`, which would then != `64` decimal.  So it's at this point I started to get a bit uncertain about the byte-order of the different parts of the `usbmon` trace.

Next I thought, maybe it's just the data portions of the `usbmon` trace that are in reverse byte order.  So I thought perhaps I should really be reading

```
...12010002 00000040 da0b8781 00010102 0301
```

as

```
1030 20101000 1878b0ad 04000000 20001021...
```

Nope, that doesn't seem to be right either.  The USB Specification states that the vendor Id (`0x0bda` in my case) should be at byte offset 8 for this particular string.  If we leave the above string in its original order, then the vendor Id does start at byte offset 8 (`12010002 00000040`  consumes the first 8 bytes), but if we reverse it as I have above, then it starts at byte offset 6 (`1030 20101000` only consumes the first 6 bytes).

So my best *guess* now is that `usbmon` displays everything big-endian, accept that it switches to reverse byte order *within* each 4-byte word, but for *data only*.  Can anyone offer some clarification on whether this is correct, or whether there may be something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

May be a bit late for you but I've tried usbmon (and found it OK)

you may want to take a look at evtest

http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Evtest